# parse filename using string [java]

Tags: java, regex, parsing

What regex pattern do I need to parse a filename like this: `"Ab12_Cd9023-2000-12-04-No234.nekiRtt3434GGG"`, where the parsed elements are: `"Ab12_Cd9023"`(name), `"2000"`(year), `"12"`(month), `"04"`(day), `"234"`(number), `"nekiRtt3434GGG"`(suffix). The sequence is always the same: `name-yyyy-MM-dd-NoNN.suffix`.

I want to use the `pattern` + `matcher` objects to solve that.

Comment: Do you want to validate whether input string should match this pattern?

Comment: the main thing is that I parse out all the elements

Comment: But what have you tried ? Are you able to use a matcher, have you define the regex ? Or are you hoping for us to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most nice looking solution that I found:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(?<name>\\w+)-"
            + "(?<year>\\d{4})-"
            + "(?<month>\\d{2})-"
            + "(?<day>\\d{2})-"
            + "No(?<number>\\d+)."
            + "(?<suffix>\\w+)$");

Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(file.getName());
        if(!m.matches())
           //some code if the pattern doesnt match

//this is how you acces the parsed strings:
m.group("year")
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

```
([a-bA-B0-9_])-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([04]{2})-No(.+)\.(.+)$
```

If you use this as pattern, each of the () signifies one part of the string you want to capture.

Comment: how do I get out elements then?

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.+)-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-No(.+)\.(.+)$");

...

    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        int day = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4));
        String number = matcher.group(5);
        String suffix = matcher.group(6);
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("year: " + year);
        System.out.println("month: " + month);
        System.out.println("day: " + day);
        System.out.println("number: " + number);
        System.out.println("suffix: " + suffix);
    } else {
        // error: does not match
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is always the same why not simply split it using - or . like this:

```
    String filename = "Ab12_Cd9023-2000-12-04-No234.nekiRtt3434GGG";
    String[] parts = filename.split("-|\\.");
    for(String p : parts)
        System.out.println(p);
```